R data scraping JSON from API
I am attempting to data scrape public data on a variety of police statistics from the relatively new nypdonline.org website, which can be accessed in a variety of ways. The main ways to normally query this data is through either the online lookup tool, located at https://nypdonline.org/link/2, or by using a unique Tax ID directly, for example: http://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=938661.
Ideally I would want an R script to go through a list of Tax IDs, which are unique identifiers, to pull down specific data points from the site—I’m currently looking at “Total Arrests” as this would help act as a control in regression work, but if I can get one data point I should be able to get them all.
The main problem is that the site goes through a process of querying a second URL, which I think it pulls JSON data from. My first effort was to try and use RVest to target a single page and use html_nodes() to try and select CSS elements, or XPath elements:
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- "http://oip.nypdonline.org/view/1/@TAXID=938661"
webpage <- read_html(url)
total_arrests <- webpage %>%  
html_nodes("[various CSS / xpath elements attempted here]") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()

But this produces nothing; inspecting the HTML I can see these numbers embedded (see image one, & the number 201 within the code) but I cannot find a way to actually data scrape them, presumably because the way this code is arranged their location changes dynamically or because part of their data is a random identifier.

Using dev tools in chrome I can see (image 2) that the site is sending a request to a secondary URL. I assume this is the URL I really need to query for JSON data.

My confusion may only be exactly how to do this, especially in the case of a site that seems to be querying JSON data from an MSSQL database—if I visit the following site directly I can see what appears to be JSON parameters, including a likely variable for the unique Tax ID value I would need:
http://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/

But this looks like it’s just the framework for the data, and I need a step I can't find and haven't quite understood to actually query the API for specific data. I can data scrape the above JSON page into R easily, but I end up with essentially the JSON framework without any actual data:
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
url <- "http://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/"
webpage <- read_html(url)
json_data <- html_text(html_nodes(webpage, "body"))
data_list <- fromJSON(json_data, flatten = TRUE)
View(data_list)

This very helpfully gives me JSON categories, under which the unique Tax ID value I would want to search within (also highlighted in image 3 JSON above) is probably something like:
json[[1]][["DataSource"]][["Parameters"]][[1]][["Name"]]

But I can’t quite figure out how to use this to actually query the API. Happy to even be turned in the right direction, because I think there's an element I'm just not understanding.

From the Google Chrome developer console, I found a POST url with the following content
url <- "https://oip.nypdonline.org/api/reports/1/datasource/list"
payload <- '{filters: [{key: "@TAXID", label: "TAXID", values: ["938661"]}]}'

I used httr::POST() and then looked at the result using the listviewer package
response <- httr::POST(url, content_type("application/json"), body = payload)
json <- httr::content(response, as = "text")
listviewer::jsonedit(json)

One could use jsonlite::fromJSON() to extract this as an R object, but I used the CRAN package rjsoncons to extract everything to a data.frame (tibble)
> rjsoncons::j_pivot(json, as = "tibble")
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  Label                   ImageURL CodeTemplate Items  Interactions RelatedItems
  <chr>                   <chr>    <chr>        <list> <list>       <list>      
1 "HERNANDEZ, GREGORY D … https:/… "HERNANDEZ,… <list> <list [0]>   <list [0]>  

or just some of it using JMESpath
rjsoncons::j_pivot(json, "[0].Items", as = "tibble")
## # A tibble: 6 × 9
##   Id                Label Value CodeTemplate LabelAlignment LabelFont LabelColor
##   <chr>             <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr>          <chr>     <list>    
## 1 a2fded09-5439-4b… Rank: "POL… {Value}      text-right     12px Ari… <chr [1]> 
## 2 20e891ce-1dcf-4d… Appo… "7/1… {Value}      text-right     12px Ari… <NULL>    
## 3 1692f3bf-ed70-4b… Comm… "049… {Value}      text-right     12px Ari… <chr [1]> 
## 4 8a2bcb6f-e064-44… Assi… "7/5… {Value}      text-right     12px Ari… <NULL>    
## 5 0ec90f94-b636-47… Ethn… "HIS… {Value}      text-right     12px Ari… <chr [1]> 
## 6 42f74dfc-ee54-4b… Shie… "264… {Value}      text-right     12px Ari… <NULL>    
## # ℹ 2 more variables: ValueAlignment <chr>, ValueFont <chr>
rjsoncons::j_pivot(json, "[0].Items", as = "tibble") |>
    dplyr::select(Label, Value)
## A tibble: 6 × 2
## Label             Value                                                       
## <chr>             <chr>                                                       
## Rank:             "POLICE OFFICER"                                            
## Appointment Date: "7/11/2005 12:00:00 AM"                                     
## Command:          "049 PRECINCT"                                              
## Assignment Date:  "7/5/2006 12:00:00 AM"                                      
## Ethnicity:        "HISPANIC                                                  …
## Shield No:        "26400   "                                                 

Maybe that gets you a bit further down the road?

Thank you for this! This got me past my critical misunderstanding--I had tried to use a POST() command and throw it out when I got an error message, and I'm still not totally clear why it happens sometimes and not others (maybe an issue with cookies?) but I believe I can actually work out the rest of the scrape from here so this has solved my real dilemma.
